# Returning another model's results in an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a simple one-to-many relationship between two tables

```
class Table < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_may :legs
end

class Leg < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :table
end
```

When I run the following query, it returns a list of `Table` model objects.

```
Table.joins(:legs).where("legs.type = 'short'")
# => [<Table id: 1>, <Table id: 1>]
```

Because a `Table` can have many `legs` that satisfy the above query criteria, I sometimes receive duplicate `Table` instances in my result.

It would be much easier (especially in situations much more complex than this) to be able to query on `Table` but have it return a result set of `Leg` objects

```
Table.joins(:legs).where("legs.type = 'short'")
# => [<Leg id: 1>, <Leg id: 2>]
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Edit: To be clear, I'm aware I could go through and `map` each object to get the result I want. But that gets tricky with one-to-many relationships. And so I'm looking for a more "native" ActiveRecord way to do it

Edit 2: I'm also aware I can query directly on `Leg` - that's not the question. The heart of the question is "is it possible to query on `Table` but return a list of `Leg` objects?". The context for this is beyond the scope of the question, but I've come across a need for it when querying polymorphic associations when one model maps to many other model types.

Comment: Not sure if this has any bearing on your question, but in both MySQL and PostgreSQL 'table' is a reserved word, and should not be used as the name of a table.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of Tables, or of Legs?

Comment: @mysmallidea - thanks for the note about the reserved work. A poor example choice on my end. As mentioned in the question, I'm trying to query on Table but return a list of `Leg` objects.

Comment: @user2490003 I understand your question and am trying to do the same.  Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @Kamilski81- it seems like it's not possible. All the answers are just workarounds that query using `Leg` - I guess it's just not a supported use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird workaround but you can do:

```
Leg.find_by_sql(Table.joins(:legs).where("legs.type = 'short'").select("DISTINCT legs.*").to_sql)
```

which convert the core query to raw sql, then run that raw sql on the leg model. As long as the result have all the field of the model getting queried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want:
`Leg.where(type: 'short')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a class method on your `Table` model

```
def self.short_legs
  Leg.where(type: 'short')
end
```

then call it as `Table.short_legs`

Comment: This will work, but it's more of a workaround than an answer. It's still querying on `Leg` fundamentally.

Comment: You're trying to retrieve leg objects right ? That is you're trying to get the records in a `legs` table underneath .. It's impossible to get a list of `legs` without hitting the legs table ?

Comment: Querying the table is not the issue. `Table.joins(:legs).where("legs.type = 'short'")` is a query that joins both the `Table` and `Leg` db tables, and filters on a particular column. But by default that statement only returns the `Table` records (in other words the `SELECT` part of the query it generates is `SELECT tables.*`). All I'm trying to do is force it to use something else for the `SELECT` statement. Specifically - `SELECT legs.* FROM tables t JOIN legs l ON t.id = l.table_id WHERE blah blah;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.joins(:legs)
     .where(legs: { type: 'short' })
     .select('DISTINCT legs.*')
```

This will instantiate a Table object, with all of the fields of Leg. Which is weird, but it will work because of duck-typing.